# Windows environment variable resolution error

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

I am trying to put the JAVA JDK path into the Windows `PATH` environment variable.

I changed/inserted the appropriate variables and got the command `javac` to be working yesterday, but when I tried the same thing today, I am getting the *command not recognized* error.

Here are the values of the relevant variables (**on a fresh cmd instance**):

```
>> echo %JAVA_HOME%
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

>> echo %PATH%
C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Users\anmol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\anmol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\;C:\Users\anmol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\
```

I tried to avoid the spaces present in `'Program Files'` by writing `JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_101`, but the error persisted.

Also, if I open a cmd and type `set path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%path%` and then in the same session type `javac`, it is recognized correctly.

Can anyone tell what is going on and how to set the PATH correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have modified PATH with the  `set` command, which applies the changes to the current terminal. To make it a persistent system wide setting, use `setx` instead.

You'll need both, PATH and JAVA_HOME in the system environment.

Note that ` does not modify the current terminal's environment settings:

```
NOTE: 1) SETX writes variables to the master environment in the registry.

      2) On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool
         will be available in future command windows but not in the
         current CMD.exe command window.
```

What has happened in your case? You have set the PATH environment variable at a time where JAVA_HOME was not known yet. In that case, %JAVA_HOME% becomes part of PATH **literally**. The following example demonstrates that:

```
C:\>set X=%A%

C:\>set A=something

C:\>set X
X=%A%

C:\>set B=something

C:\>set X=%B%

C:\>set X
X=something
```

To fix it, set JAVA_HOME using `setx`, close the terminal and open a new one. Then use `setx` to set PATH, close the terminal and open a new one.

*or*

set JAVA_HOME using `setx`, set JAVA_HOME using `set` to update the console. Then use `setx` to set PATH, close the terminal and open a new one.

Comment: The `PATH` variable already contains the JDK path (before I executed the set command). Why is the error still coming?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi: you have set PATH before you set JAVA_HOME. I have updated my answer

Comment: Okay, but then how to rectify it?

Comment: To fix it, set JAVA_HOME using setx, close the terminal and open a new one. Then use setx to set PATH, close the terminal and open a new one.